# using phonegap-facebook-plugin in simple cordova android app

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get facebook-plugin on [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) link working on my android emulator after building it using cordova

I have used below login function (given as example on the github documentation page) after viewready has been fired.

```
facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(
            function(response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            },
            function(response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            });
```

my app crashes with the message "Unfortunately app has stopped working". I have done following steps till now :
-- create new cordova project

--add android platform to it

--add phonegap plugin to cordova project by below command

```
cordova -d plugin add /Users/your/path/here/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

--added keyhash to facebook developer account as well

--added faceboook-android-sdk reference by using below command inside platforms/android

```
android update project --target 3 --path . --library ../../facebook/
```

--build and run on emulatorusing  below command

```
cordova emulate android
```

I read many forums and **[this](http://bobnisco.com/blog/view/use-facebook-login-phonegap-3x-apps)** blogpost for finding a solution and all of them use the below code

```
if (typeof CDV === 'undefined') {
    alert('CDV variable does not exist. Check that you have included cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js correctly');
}
if (typeof FB === 'undefined') {
    alert('FB variable does not exist. Check that you have included the Facebook JS SDK file.');
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    try {
        FB.init({
            appId: "YOUR_FB_APP_ID",
            nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
            useCachedDialogs: false
        });
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}, false);
```

The issue is the two files(`cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js`  and `Facebook JS SDK file` ) that are mentioned in the code above and that everyone is talking about are nowhere to be found in the folder i downloaded from the github page.

As per i understand , even though i haven't installed the facebook app in emulator, the plugin should open a web view with a login screen if i call login function. But currently the app crashes if i write the login code i posted above.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That documentation is deprecated, try this:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(['public_profile'],
    function(response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    function(response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
```

But this wouldn't help you a lot because you will stuck in next step, facebook does not run callbacks functions at login method, please let me know if login method will work for you.